# Get voice stream during android call

Tags: android, wifi, call, voice

I have wifi connection between java desktop app and android app. I need to transfer opponent's voice during call to desktop side and also transer my voice from desktop's microphone to opponent. How can I do it? How can I get input and output streams of call?

Comment: An application can't write data into the uplink of a voice call. The only way I see that you could do this in a manner that would work with the vast majority of devices out there is if your desktop app simulated a Bluetooth Handsfree (with the help of a BT dongle). I believe that MecApp (a commercial software) can do this, so it should be technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not handle gsm call data (neither send over uplink nor receive over downlink). I think you can try sip calls if that meets your requirement.

Comment: But such thing implemented in this application over bluetooth or wifi : [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=justPhone.remotePhone).